# A sensible way combine two stacked bar charts in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have one chart that has several stacked bars with identical components - one for each category.
Each of the components of those bars can also be represented with a stacked bar chart, like the following example:

[image: Example of current situation]

In what way can this all be represented in a single chart?

Comment: Can you post a link to a image (even hand-drawn if you think it might help)? The way it is presented it's a little confusing.

Comment: You're right. I added an example.

Comment: I understand now what you have, but if you're asking if you can combine (as if on a single block, both charts were displayed) both charts into one, in Office, than no, you can't do that, apart from serious VBA programming. I still feel like I haven't figured out what you want (or am thinking some very complex presentation systems).

Comment: There's a couple different ways you could accomplish this with creative data organization and chart manipulation.  What are you wanting to show? There's a lot of data points, do you have a message focus you're trying to emphasize (e.g. comparing one data point to another, or emphasizing a particular point)?

Comment: I don't have a particular picture in mind. If the above could be presented in one item that would allow the viewer to infer everything that can be inferred from looking at the two above, that could work. Clearly, this would be a lot more complex visually, but that's not a problem. In a way, the question is: "what are some possible visual representations for this?"

Comment: What you are now asking is way too dependent on the data being presented. For instance, I'm not going to represent [stress test results](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_tensile_strength) in a box plot. A scatter plot would be most useful. Unless you state what data you need to handle, this will become too hypothetical (or non-practical).

Comment: Both charts show components. One shows them as values, one shows them as categories on the X axis. I cannot quite picture what you are after as the end result. Please use the drawing tools to mock up a sample of the desired chart and then post that with some sample data.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to help. As I'd said before, I was not looking for a way to achieve a result I had in mind  but rather for ideas. I don't know if a question here should or can be marked as closed, but if yes, please do so.

Comment: Maybe I’m just slow, but I’m struggling to understand what your data look like.  Can you post some examples of that, and/or give us a ***real*** explanation of what you’re talking about?  For example, why doesn’t the second chart have nine bars: cat1.comp1, cat1.comp2, cat1.comp3, cat2.comp1, …?  Does the Component 1 bar represent cat1.comp1+cat2.comp1+cat3.comp1?  And, just out of curiosity, are the totals really equal, or are you just scaling them?

Comment: Do you want to divide each of the component bars in the first chart according to the proportions in the second?

Answer (score 2):

Recomending anything without a better data sample is nigh impossible.

If you flip the data for the second chart, so that "Data 1" etc is in the X axis and the components are again the values, then there is a base for combination, because the two charts have a common denomitator: The components are the values, and there are two different x axes, one for "categories" and one for "data".

You can then use a clustered stacked chart, where the stacks for "category 1" sits right next to "data 1", "category 2" next to "data 2", etc. Something like this:

[image]

This screenshot is from Jon Peltier's tutorial about "Clustered Stacked Column and Bar Charts". You can find it here: http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/clustered-stacked-column-bar-charts/